# List rows that contain part of the same data. Part is not always the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list similar to this in a table called devices:

```
devicename   icon_color
Device1      icon_red
Device1 (1)  icon_green
sfsdfsd      icon_green
aaaaaaa (1)  icon_red
bbbbbbb      icon_green
bbbbbbb (1)  icon_red
bbbbbbb (2)  icon_red
```

I need to output:

A- a list of all devices for which the devicename is similar (just for control). By similar I mean devices that have the same first part of the name. What would differ between each would be what is in parenthesis. So as an example, the query should list bbbbbbb, bbbbbbb (1) and bbbbbbb (2)as "similar".

In this list it would be:

```
devicename   icon_color
Device1      icon_red
Device1 (1)  icon_green
bbbbbbb      icon_green
bbbbbbb (1)  icon_red
bbbbbbb (2)  icon_red
```

B- The result of A- but filtered on `icon_color='icon_red'` (that's really what I need here). In this list it would be:

```
devicename   icon_color
Device1      icon_red
bbbbbbb (1)  icon_red
bbbbbbb (2)  icon_red
```

I've tried many things without success. Any ideas?

Comment: By similar you mean that all of the name up to the first space matches all of another name up to it's first space?

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: By similar I mean devices that have the same first part of the name. What would differ between each would be what is in parenthesis. So as an example, the query should list bbbbbbb, bbbbbbb (1) and bbbbbbb (2)as "similar". I hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . This would seem to do what you want:

```
select d.*
from devices d
where d.icon_color = 'icon_red' and
      ( (d.device_name not like '% %' and
         exists (select 1
                 from devices d2
                 where d2.device_name like d.device_name + ' %'
                )
        ) or
        (d.device_name like '% %' and
         exists (select 1
                 from devices d2
                 where d.device_name like d2.device_name + ' %'
                )
        )
       );
```

This looks for a similar device name followed with a space.

Comment: Maybe ask OP for clarification first, then the aim of the question will be clear and documented, rather than remaining buried/obscured within the subtlies of the code in an answer that may happen to be accepted. It's a worthy goal to help people solve their problems, but we want to build a knowledge base that has value for future visitors.

Comment: By similar I mean devices that have the same first part of the name. What would differ between each would be what is in parenthesis. So as an example, the query should list bbbbbbb, bbbbbbb (1) and bbbbbbb (2)as "similar". I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @druid . . . It would be the same if you stop at the first space, given your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

for your first requirement, using `having` clause

```
select * from devices where exists 
    (select devicename from devices
    group by devicename 
    having count(1) > 1)
```

for your 2nd requirement, just add `where` clause

```
select * from devices where exists 
    (select devicename from devices
    group by devicename 
    having count(1) > 1)
where icon_color = 'icon_red'
```